# Why do the labels in the PDF file become garbage characters?

Tags: hyperref

Yesterday, I used the package `hyperref` to get hyperlinks. Why the PDF file's  labels on the left of the application window becomes full of garbage characters?
I searched Google and know the reason about GBK  and Unicode.

```
     \documentclass[UTF8 ]{ctexart}
     \usepackage{hyperref}
     \begin{document  }
    \tableofcontents
    \section{介绍}
          大家好，我叫汤书桃
    \section{常州}
       中国江苏常州有一所综合大学，常州大学
    \section{结论}
    我非常喜欢latex
  \end{document}
```

However, I don't know how to convert it. By the way, I use the UTF-8 to write the LaTeX file. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I get no garbage, but *introduction*, *changzhou* and *conclusion* in the bookmarks. Please, note that spaces are significant, so you should type `\end{document}` (no spaces inside) and similarly for the other places.

Comment: @egreg,I use the Chinese character in the document ,I have edited the question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use GBK as encoding, prefer UTF-8, to begin with.

You also need to tell `hyperref` that you're using Unicode.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{介绍}

大家好，我叫汤书桃

\section{常州}
中国江苏常州有一所综合大学，常州大学

\section{结论}
我非常喜欢\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Note that no space should be in the braces around the name of an environment.

[image]

Comment: ,Dear friend,thanks very much.I tried many times yesterday but failed .I think latex is very very useful and powerful and interesting .

Comment: @Tangshutao You're welcome. I know no Chinese, but some LaTeX. `;-)`